# not able to pass data to controller using Ajax with jquery ,CodeIgniter (PHP framework)

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, codeigniter

passing data to controller using AJAX
 this is script i have written to pass data to controller but data is not passed to the controller

this is the input data i want to pass

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <table class="table table-striped b-t b-light text-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Question</th>
                <th>answer</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($quet as $row) { ?>
                <tr>
                <td ><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $row['question']; ?>
                </td>
                <td><input type='text' name='name' required="required" class="form-control" placeholder='Enter Your Answer'></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>  
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" id ="next" type="button" >Next</button>
```

and the script

```
<script>
           $(document).ready(function($){
    $("#next").click(function(){

     var array = $("name").val()

     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          datatype:"json",
          url: BASE_URL+"/student/add",
          data: 'data='+array,
          contentType:'application/json',
          processData: false,              
          error: function(response) {console.log('ERROR '+Object.keys(response)); },
          success: function(response) {
              console.log(response)

          }});

        return false;
    });  
});
</script>
```

and the student controller

```
function add(){

      if($this->student_model->add($this->input->post()))
        {
        $response['success'] = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
        $response['success'] = FALSE;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);  
    }
```

Comment: first of all you've to change the name of the input textbox from 'name'. Then you've to assign an id or a unique class to it. after that you could call the jquery as `var array = $("#id").val()`

Comment: @Hoja.M.A i have added code for input text

Comment: where is the id="next" button, it's in your code or not..?

Comment: @HardikRanpariya yes id ="next" button it is in code i have edit the question

Comment: okey, then check my code again, i edit that code.

Comment: @HardikRanpariya thanks for replay i tried your code but still data not passed to controller , may there is any other problem associated with it ,i need to check

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Your data may be in wrong format

```
data: {'data':array}
```

**EDIT**

```
 <input type='text' name='answer' id='answer' required="required" class="form-control" placeholder='Enter Your Answer' />
<script>
   $(document).ready(function($){
        $("#next").click(function(){

        var array = $("#answer").val() // see the change name to id, see the html also

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
              url: BASE_URL+"/student/add",
              data:{'data':array},
              error: function(response) {console.log('ERROR '+Object.keys(response)); },
              success: function(response) {
                 console.log(response)
              }});
         });  
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to check the browser utility to monitor the ajax request when u click on the next button

Answer (score 0):

Also check the array is received properly in you JS

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function($){
    $("#next").click(function(){

     var array = $("#id").val()

     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          datatype:"json",
          url: BASE_URL+"/student/add",
          data: {
            'data':array
          },
          contentType:'application/json',
          processData: false,              
          error: function(response) {console.log('ERROR '+Object.keys(response)); },
          success: function(response) {
              console.log(response)

          }});

        return false;
    });  
});
</script>
```

In your controller you should change `$this->input->post()` to`$this->input->post('data')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change following in your code.

**In the Script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
    $("#next").click(function(){

     var array = $("input[name]").val();

     $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: BASE_URL+"/student/add",
          data: {'data':array},            
          error: function(response) {console.log('ERROR '+Object.keys(response)); },
          success: function(response) {
              console.log(response)

          },
          datatype:"json"
     });

        return false;
    });  
});
</script>
```

**In the Student Controller**

```
function add(){

      if($this->student_model->add($this->input->post('data')))
        {
            $response['success'] = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $response['success'] = FALSE;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);  
    }
```

I hope this help.

Comment: var array = $("#name").val() for this he has to add id attribute in his input element?

Comment: @Hardik Ranpariya `$("#name").val()`  so i have to assign id to input field id="name"

Comment: i already change this. you can now not need to assign id to input field id="name"

Comment: @Hardik Ranpariya well its not showing any error but data is not submitted

Answer (score 0):

From your mentioned code, you need to check these points :

1) As you are using `contentType:'application/json',` so use the data format as `data: {'data':array}`

2) Finally check whether the url `url: BASE_URL+"/student/add",` is accessible or not.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: var array = $("name").val() what is the relation ship with class here? If there is a class "name" then it must be referred like $(".name").val() (dot infront)

Comment: @Kiren, yes you are right, I did not notice it, I thought it is $(".name").val() but it was $("name").val().

Comment: @jenis input text is contain in this div                        `<div class="form-group">
 <table class="table table-striped b-t b-light text-sm">
  <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Question</th>
   <th>answer</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <?php foreach ($quet as $row) { ?>
   <tr>
   <td ><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
   <td>
   <?php echo $row['question']; ?>
   </td>
   <td><input type='text' name='name' required="required" class="form-control" placeholder='Enter Your Answer'></td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>  
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>`

Comment: @SoftwareDev, Just try and make use of Firebug (Mozilla addon) Console so that you can debug and figure out the root cause.
And just try this ajax url value  => url: BASE_URL+"/index.php/student/add",